# Symfony 3 login form in multiple controllers

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.4

I followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) tutorial on how to build a login form in Symfony 3 and everything works fine.

However I'd like to use the same login form on multiple pages ("/" and "/login"). Unfortunately I can always get only one of these pages working based on how I configure the "login_path" and "check_path" in security.yaml.

So it's either

```
form_login:
                  login_path: login
                  check_path: login
```

or

```
form_login:
                  login_path: /
                  check_path: /
```

I've tried to add another firewall specifically for the login page to use both at once, but without success, my form on /login would then seem to submit and would redirect to default_target_path, but the user wouldn't be logged in. I've also tried to set the 'action' variable in the function createForm in controller to make the login form submit to /login even on the index page, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you share your login form code? Is it a simple HTML form or did you use the Symfony form builder?

Comment: I used a builder as I was planning to use the form on multiple pages: class LoginForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('_username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Uživatelské jméno'))
            ->add("_password",PasswordType::class,array('label' => 'Heslo'))
            ->add('Odeslat', SubmitType::class)
        ;

    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a second entry with a different name? I'm not sure it will work, but technically different providers with different names are allowed. And there's no requirement they actually have different providers or different implementations.

```
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
        alternative
            # ...
            form_login:
                login_path: /
                check_path: /
```

Comment: As I mentioned I've tried doing this and it resulted in both forms submitting but the second one not actually logging in the user. However after more searching I found out that it's because the two firewalls didn't share the same security context so the solution was to add "context : some_context_name" to the parameters of both firewalls in security.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the user to the login page if they are not logged in.

```
//Assuming this is the action for the "/" route

public function indexAction($name)
{
  //If not logged in
  if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('/login');  
  }

  ...//If logged in
}
```

You could possibly just render the login page rather than redirecting.

Comment: I could but that wasn't really what I wanted to do, I wanted to display the login form on both of these pages.

Comment: Seems like you would want to go down the route ASOlivieri mentioned. Looking at the comments it sounds like you got that working. You should Accept his answer if so